# IsTextSelectionEnabled in WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, textselection

How to add the Property **`IsTextSelectionEnabled`** in WPF TextBlock. It shows me an compile time error "**The property 'IsTextSelectionEnabled' was not found in type 'TextBlock'**"

> Note: I found the Property `IsTextSelectionEnabled` in Microsoft
>   Website.

The Website Link : [IsTextSelectionEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.istextselectionenabled.aspx)

Kindly assist me how to use the Property in TextBlock.

My XAML Source Code is

```
<TextBlock Text="TextBlock" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"/>
```

Comment: are you developing a windows app (win8 app/ win10 app) , it seems like this property only exists for WinRT/Universal Windows apps.

Comment: Yes. Windows Application.